# GPUImage ChromaKeyBlendFilter

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

I am using the `GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter` and getting undesired output. I either have my camera input correct, or my background image thats blending not both. I have a view of size 930x620, and my background image is 1200x800 which scales to 930x620 while maintaining aspect ratio.

```
filter = GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter()
filter?.setColorToReplaceRed(0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0)
filter?.thresholdSensitivity = CGFloat(effectSlider)
filter?.thresholdSensitivity = 0.40
filter?.smoothing = 0.14
```

If I use the below the background image shows correctly, however, the preview of the image is stretched, if I remove preview image is correct, but background is skewed.

```
filter?.forceProcessing(at: overlayImage.frame.size) (the overlay is again 1200x800/930x620)
```

I am using `kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill`.

Comment: please add desired o/p image and actual o/p for more clarity !!

Comment: @ShivamGaur final output is 1200x800

Answer (score 0):

```
func chromaKeyBlendOneVideoWithTexture() {
    // background texture
    let textureImage = UIImage(named: "texture.jpg")!
    let sourceImage = PictureInput(image: textureImage)
    sourceImage.processImage()

    do {
        let movieUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mp4")!
        let movieInput = try MovieInput(url: movieUrl, playAtActualSpeed: true)

        let chromaKeyBlendFilter = ChromaKeyBlend()

        // first add green channel video than background texture.
        movieInput --> chromaKeyBlendFilter --> renderView
        sourceImage --> chromaKeyBlendFilter

        movieInput.start()
    } catch {
        print("Couldn't process movie with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```